# pandas join DataFrame force suffix?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I force a suffix on a merge or join.  I understand it's possible to provide one if there is a collision but in my case I'm merging df1 with df2 which doesn't cause any collision but then merging again on df2 which uses the suffixes but I would prefer for each merge to have a suffix because it gets confusing if I do different combinations as you could imagine.

Comment: Why not just concat or append df1 and df2 together but rename the clashing columns in df2 so you can id where the original data came from?

Comment: See my answer for an updated version using the [add_suffix](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) added in 0.24.2

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could force a suffix on the actual DataFrame:

```
In [11]: df_a = pd.DataFrame([[1], [2]], columns=['A'])

In [12]: df_b = pd.DataFrame([[3], [4]], columns=['B'])

In [13]: df_a.join(df_b)
Out[13]: 
   A  B
0  1  3
1  2  4
```

By appending to its column's names:

```
In [14]: df_a.columns = df_a.columns.map(lambda x: str(x) + '_a')

In [15]: df_a
Out[15]: 
   A_a
0    1
1    2
```

Now joins won't need the suffix correction, whether they collide or not:

```
In [16]: df_b.columns = df_b.columns.map(lambda x: str(x) + '_b')

In [17]: df_a.join(df_b)
Out[17]: 
   A_a  B_b
0    1    3
1    2    4
```

Comment: I'm doing this now.  I guess in the end, it would be nice to save the step and provide a suffix to the join/merge functions.  I'll mark this as the correct answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Instead of using the `lambda`, you can just add to the column index-- `df_a.columns += "_a"` if they're all strings.  Or add `df_a.columns.astype("str") + "_a"` if not.

Comment: @DSM would this modify the col names in place?  My goal is to not modify them inplace but to just temporarily modify them

Comment: @stgtscc: it would do exactly the same thing as Andy's answer.  If you want to change column names *not* in place, you could do `df_a.rename(columns=lambda x: x+"_a").join(df_b.rename(columns=lambda x: x+"_b"))` or something.

Comment: this would be a nice addition to merge in pandas.

Comment: Someone should open a feature request. I think I might do it.

Comment: I took my time on that feature request. [Someone beat me to it.](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17834)

Answer (score 26):

As of pandas version 0.24.2 you can add a suffix to column names on a DataFrame using the [add_suffix](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) method.

This makes a one-liner merge command with force-suffix more bearable, for example:

```py
df_merged = df1.merge(df2.add_suffix('_2'))
```

Comment: But then you have a problem of column names changing before the merge

Comment: @thebeancounter Can't you just change the right_on and left_on so they match up with the suffices?

Answer (score 8):

Pandas merge will give the new columns a suffix when there is already a column with the same name, When i need to force the new columns with a suffix, i create an empty column with the name of the column that i want to join.

```
df["colName"] = "" #create empty column 
df.merge(right = "df1", suffixes = ("_a","_b"))
```

You can later drop the empty column.

You could do the same for more than one columns, or for every column in df.columns.values

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've been using to `pandas.merge` two DataFrames and force suffixing:

```
def merge_force_suffix(left, right, **kwargs):
    on_col = kwargs['on']
    suffix_tupple = kwargs['suffixes']

    def suffix_col(col, suffix):
        if col != on_col:
            return str(col) + suffix
        else:
            return col

    left_suffixed = left.rename(columns=lambda x: suffix_col(x, suffix_tupple[0]))
    right_suffixed = right.rename(columns=lambda x: suffix_col(x, suffix_tupple[1]))
    del kwargs['suffixes']
    return pd.merge(left_suffixed, right_suffixed, **kwargs)
```

Comment: From this feature [request](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17834#issuecomment-964104103) adding: `if col not in on_col:` instead of `if col != on_col` would make it work on multiple on_cols. From that discussion  it seems this is still an acceptable workaround for the use case, other than using [add_suffix](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) as pointed out in other answers.